# The request requires buffering data to succeed HttpClient

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to send a dictionary content to a server with `POST` method

```
public async Task<T> postConnection(string GETParam, Dictionary<string, string> values, bool isRegistration = false)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    string responseString;
    try
    { 
        using (var client = new HttpClient() { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000 }) 
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tocken);
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
            responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
```

But when I run the code it gives me the error
`WebException: The request requires buffering data to succeed HttpClient`.

I don't want to make the request using `WebRequest` or `WebClient`, I want to use only `HttpClient`.

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25509233/4614264) exists already with the same exception occurring when trying to send a `head request` says that the problem is occurred only on `Xamarin` projects, but the question wasn't answered yet. It's just mentioned that he solved the problem by using `WebRequest`.

What is the error with this code on `Xamarin.Forms`? and How could it be solved using `HttpClient`?

### edit

## Full exception

```
{System.Net.WebException: The request requires buffering data to succeed.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0005e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1005 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2 endFunction, System.Action`1 endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00014] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/FutureFactory.cs:550 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x003d6] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:372 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x000a9] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:276 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at HuraApp.API.Connection`1+<postConnection>d__1[T].MoveNext () [0x0011c] in C:\Users\Nullsky\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\HuraApp\HuraApp\HuraApp\API\Connection.cs:43 }
```

Comment: Do you have set the right permission?

Comment: @Tinwor Sorry, but I think that I don't need to set the internet and network permissions since `Xamarin` adds them automatically in the `Manifest` file.

Comment: Is there an InnerException in the exception that gets raised? Also, what platform (iOS? Android?)

Comment: No, there's no `InnerException`. I'm running it on android emulator.

Comment: Instead of `response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);` try `response = await client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url) { Content = content }, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);`

Comment: Have you tried turning on all debug options such as .Net Framework source stepping and `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` just before making the post in order of catching the native exception?
Read more:
http://xamariniac.hlinteractive.se/index.php/2016/09/22/debugging-xamarin-and-cross-platform-exceptions/

Comment: @YazanWYusuf How does your url looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the same question you have linked in making a head request , please see the below link where the solution is given one of them in xamarin forums,  who had the same issue in making a POST request (200) to Google url.

The resolution in that case was changing the URL to an actual page and not a redirect.

Here 's the link [Solution for the issue](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23023/http-head-request)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the Mono source code for HttpWebRequest, it looks like the server is issuing a redirect, and HttpWebRequest (used under the covers by HttpClient) is not handling that.

I'm not exactly sure what version of the Mono source is being used, but this looks like a likely candidate: 
https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/cc3f4c60379c3839dd4259e171bb4539d21f2157/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs

That version has a "throw" at line 1005 in HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse, which matches the exception stack you're seeing.  The string in the exception, "The request requires buffering data to succeed" comes from HttpWebRequest.Redirect.

The next step would be to use Fiddler (or similar) to replicate the exact POST message the Xamarin client is attempting to see the response it gets from the server.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

Downloads entire response before finishing, so it does not use any buffering. The only alternative is to use,

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(url);
request.Content = content;
var response = await client.SendAsync(request, 
      HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

`HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` option makes `HttpClient` return from `SendAsync` just after downloading headers. And you can await on reading the content.

Answer (score 1):

Is this happening on iOS and/or Android?

I would try changing the HttpClient handler to be the native handler. This solves a lot of problems ranging a lot of topics (TLS is a big one). For iOS, use the NSUrlSession handler and for Android, try the AndroidClientHandler. You should be able to use HttpClient for everything with Xamarin.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! This was the only option that worked for me in iOS. Android, though, worked even with AndroidClientHandler