# HttpClient PostAsync() not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, httpclient

In my Xamarin Forms App

I'm trying to Post a Json String to my webservice wich is RestFul API
when i use the following code:

```
public static async Task<bool> SaveRolAsync(Methods Method, Role Rol)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var uri = ("http://myservice.com/roles/");
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            try
            {
                var jSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
                jSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                jSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;

                var JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Rol);
                var RoleContent = new StringContent(JsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                if (Method == Methods.PUT || Method == Methods.PATCH)
                {
                    response = await client.PutAsync(uri, RoleContent);
                }

                if (Method == Methods.POST)
                {
                    response = await client.PostAsync(uri, RoleContent);
                }

                if (Method == Methods.DELETE)
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }

                return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;

            }
            catch (JsonException jse)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Exceptions Throws here
            // @T This line i got The request requires buffering data to succeed
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The Exception throws:

> The request requires buffering data to succeed

Stack Trace:

> {System.Net.WebException: The request requires buffering data to
>   succeed.   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse
>   (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00064] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic
>   (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction,
>   System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult]
>   promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00014] in
>   :0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in :0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult
>   () [0x00000] in <a66f207c1e5949e9a252c01e27bbd34e>:0    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext ()
>   [0x0041e] in <566d6cf6576345098cb5e08ad43d5e78>:0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in <a66f207c1e5949e9a252c01e27bbd34e>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in
>   <a66f207c1e5949e9a252c01e27bbd34e>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in
>   <a66f207c1e5949e9a252c01e27bbd34e>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in
>   <a66f207c1e5949e9a252c01e27bbd34e>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult
>   () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClient+c__async0.MoveNext ()
>   [0x000f3] in <566d6cf6576345098cb5e08ad43d5e78>:0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in :0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   MyAPP.Webservice+d__4.MoveNext () [0x000d0] in
>   C:\MyProject\Classes\Webservice.cs:140 }

**Also Tried: SendAsync() Ty M. Wiśnicki **

```
public static async Task<bool> SaveRolAsync(MediwareLib.Methods Method, Role Rol)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var uri = (BaseRequestUrl + "roles/");
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage();

            try
            {
                var jSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
                jSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                jSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;

                var JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Rol);

                var RoleContent = new StringContent(JsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                if (Method == MediwareLib.Methods.PUT || Method == MediwareLib.Methods.PATCH)
                {
                    request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, uri);
                    request.Content = RoleContent;

                    response = await client.SendAsync(request,
                    HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
                }

                if (Method == MediwareLib.Methods.POST)
                {
                    request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
                    request.Content = RoleContent;

                    response = await client.SendAsync(request,
                    HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
                }

                if (Method == MediwareLib.Methods.DELETE)
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                    // response = await client.DeleteAsync(uri + Rol.Id);
                }

                return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;

            }
            catch (JsonException jse)
            {
                Globals.Log("SaveRolAsync: " + jse.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Globals.Log("SaveRolAsync: " + ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: So what did your research show? Did you read [The request requires buffering data to succeed HttpClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368724/the-request-requires-buffering-data-to-succeed-httpclient) and [Head request with HttpClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509233/head-request-with-httpclient)? Did you notice you're sending a PUT even `if (Method == Methods.POST)`? Is your service responding with a redirect?

Comment: Ofc i did read other stackoverflow posts but i want to send a json string not a google request.

Comment: An HTTP request is an HTTP request, whether it contains search results or JSON data.

Comment: Would be nice to know in which line the exception is thrown :)

Comment: Please attach the full stack trace.

Comment: @CodeCaster No its return with Json String Data Response.Write and Response.End()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SendAsync()` with `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`  instead `PostAsync()`, the problem is with reading response, it's reading when it not ready.

```
var request = new HttpMessageRequest(yourUrl);
request.Content = yourContent;
var response = await client.SendAsync(request, 
HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

Using `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`

> The operation should complete as soon as a response is available and headers are read. The content is not read yet.

**Edit**
You can use `HttpWebRequest` instead `HttpClient`

```
   public async Task<string> PostTest(object sampleData, string uri)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Timeout = 4000; //ms
        var itemToSend = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sampleData);
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(itemToSend);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Dispose();
        }

        // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:  
        using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:  
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                var message = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return message;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Same error :( System.Net.WebException: The request requires buffering data to succeed.

Comment: @StefanvandeLaarschot You using `new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);`  but i wrote without `HttpMethod`, use with uri only.

Comment: It can't it expects HttpMethod, uri or String as Uri

Comment: Same: System.Net.WebException: The request requires buffering data to succeed.

Comment: I think the problem is with try catch block. Be sure you not block on async code. Also try run post with `client.PostAsync(uri, RoleContent).Result;` without `await`.Here you find article why cant block async http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: Without the Await ?? Since i'm using this in a android app don't want to block the UI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131560/discussion-between-m-wisnicki-and-stefan-van-de-laarschot).

Answer (score 10):

Since you are using `.Result` or `.Wait` or `await` this will end up causing a **deadlock** in your code.

you can use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in `async` methods for **preventing deadlock**

like this:

```
response = await client.PostAsync(uri, RoleContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

> you can use `ConfigureAwait(false)` wherever possible for Don't Block Async Code .